# MS Graph Client AcquireTokenForClient call never comes back in .Net 4.8 + XAML app

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, microsoft-graph-api, .net-4.8

I have a MS Graph Client creation code that i copied over from another app (.NET 4.6.2) that works flawless, into a .NET 4.8 app that uses XAML as UI.

```
public Microsoft365(BaseSource source)
        : base(source)
    {
        _ = GetGraphClient().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates a MS Graph Client based on the OAuth2 Token Data supplied via <see cref="BaseSource"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task<GraphServiceClient> GetGraphClient()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_graphClient != null)
            {
                return _graphClient;
            }

            var clientId = "<redacted>";
            var tenantId = "<redacted>";
            var clientSecret = "<redacted>";

            var scopes = new List<string> { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, tenantId)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .Build();

            var authResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
            var token = authResult.AccessToken;

            ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
            _graphClient = graphClient;

            return graphClient;
        }

        catch (MsalException msalException)
        {
            // Handle MSAL exceptions
            Console.WriteLine($"MSAL Exception: {msalException.Message}");
            // Additional handling or logging can be added here
        }
        catch (ServiceException serviceException)
        {
            // Handle Graph API exceptions
            Console.WriteLine($"Graph API Exception: {serviceException.Message}");
            // Additional handling or logging can be added here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle other exceptions
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
            // Additional handling or logging can be added here
        }

        return null;
    }
```

This code is called after adding a new DMS source and then pressing a Save Button in a XAML UI and a handover to the constructor of the BaseSource interface.

Everything goes through normally up to:
`var authResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(_scopes).ExecuteAsync();`

This call takes forever and seemingly never comes back, until eventually (over 10 minutes+).
None of the exception checckpoints are ever hit.

I get greeted with:
`Managed Debugging Assistant 'DisconnectedContext'

`Message=Managed Debugging Assistant 'DisconnectedContext' : 'Folgender Fehler beim Übergang in den COM-Kontext 0x537ae6a8 für diesen RuntimeCallableWrapper: Systemaufruf ist fehlgeschlagen. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80010100 (RPC_E_SYS_CALL_FAILED)). Dieser tritt in der Regel auf, da der COM-Kontext 0x537ae6a8, in dem dieser RuntimeCallableWrapper erstellt wurde, getrennt wurde oder aufgrund eines anderen Vorgangs ausgelastet ist. Die Schnittstellen werden aus dem aktuellen COM-Kontext (COM-Kontext 0x537ae7d0) freigegeben. Dies kann Datenbeschädigung oder -verlust zur Folge haben. Um dieses Problem zu vermeiden, müssen Sie sicherstellen, dass alle COM-Kontexte/Apartments/Threads so lange beibehalten werden und für den Kontextübergang verfügbar sind, bis die Anwendung alle RuntimeCallableWrappers, die in ihnen enthaltene COM-Komponenten darstellen, vollständig verarbeitet hat.'` and a Break Mode Tab in VS22.`

The exact same code works in a .Net 4.6.2 Console Program, and a .Net 4.8 Console Program.
I have cross checked all NuGet packages between the barebones .net 4.8 project and the .net 4.8 xaml project, they are exactly the same.

The only open issues are 13 binding issues in the XAML UI, which I don't believe matter - since they only target Visibility properties. I am happy to be proven wrong that this is indeed the root issue, since I have zero experience in XAML and it's pitfalls.

[image: XAML Binding Errors]

If any more code is needed, I will happily provide more snippets.

Comment: The error may be cross-threading.  See : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20230216-00/?p=107836&force_isolation=true. Also see : https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/998159/How-to-handle-cross-thread-exception-in-WPF-with-M?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng Thank you! It was indeed a cross threading issue. I will post an answer how it was fixed for us.

Answer (score 1):

As @jdweng proposed, this issue was rooted in cross threading.

We ended up wrapping the entire class creation in a seperate thread for Microsoft365. Exchange, FileSystem and FTP are all synchronous implmentations, where as Microsoft365 is asynchronous.

```
switch (source.Type)
            {
                case Model.SourceType.Exchange:
                    var sourceExchange = new Model.Exchange(source);
                    result = sourceExchange.IsAvailable(out errorMessage);
                    break;
                case Model.SourceType.FileSystem:
                    var sourceFilesystem = new Model.FileSystem(source);
                    result = sourceFilesystem.IsAvailable(out errorMessage);
                    break;
                case Model.SourceType.FTP:
                    var sourceFTP = new Model.FTP(source);
                    result = sourceFTP.IsAvailable(out errorMessage);
                    break;
                case Model.SourceType.Microsoft365:
                    string s = null;
                    var task = new Task<bool>(() =>
                    {
                        var microsoft365 = new Model.Microsoft365(source);
                        return microsoft365.IsAvailable(out s);
                    });
                    task.Start();
                    task.Wait();
                    result = task.Result;
                    errorMessage = s;

                    break;
            }
```

Totally odd this fixes it, but I am not asking questions anymore and will happily take this workaround.